# Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11814 Only Happens On iPhone6

Tags: objective-c, xcode, video, avfoundation, avcapturedevice

I'ved got a strange error for AVCaptureDevice that only happens on iPhone6. I'ved tried it on iPhone6S and iPad and it works fine. The error is: Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11814

Here is the error print output:

```
Unable to obtain video device input, error: Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11814 "Cannot Record" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Record, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try recording again.}
```

Here is the code snippet. There is no return in videoDevices, so it skips that. Usually its able to obtain that but not for iPhone6.

```
//get the front camera
NSArray *videoDevices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
for (AVCaptureDevice *device in videoDevices)
{
    if (device.position == AVCaptureDevicePositionFront) {
        _videoDevice = device;
        break;
    }
}

// obtain device input
NSError *error = nil;
AVCaptureDeviceInput *videoDeviceInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:_videoDevice error:&error];
if (!videoDeviceInput)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Unable to obtain video device input, error: %@", error]); <--- the print out message is from here.
    return;
}
```

How can I solve this, it only happens on iPhone6. Its been updated to latest version 12.4.6.

Comment: This might not help much, but the error name for -11814 is `AVErrorDeviceNotConnected`. It seems AV can't establish a connection to the device somehow. Does the system Camera app work on that iPhone?

Comment: it does work with the normal camera native app. Its really strange, my other devices are ok.

Comment: Check app permissions in phone settings. It may have blocked camera access, somewhere in the past, when you did not allow access on usual privacy prompt, or later on.

Comment: in the app permission. i see camera permission turned on. screen is practically white.

Comment: HI @Axil you find any solution ? I am facing same issue with iPhone X running iOS 16.7